# How do I create a copy of an array of objects which some are subclasses of each other?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, copy

I have this array of consisting of multiple objects of type PublicTransportation
`PublicTransportation[] toCopyTransport = new PublicTransportation[12];`

However, some of these objects inside toCopyTransport are also subclasses of the superclass PublicTransportation (e.g.: CityBus).

If they were all the superclass type, I could simply use the copy constructor. However, since some of these objects are subclasses and contain more attributes than the superclass objects, not all attributes will be copied by using the copy constructor of PublicTransportation.

Is there a way to utilize the copy constructors of all the different subclasses as well in order to duplicate this array?

Comment: Can you define a method called `copy` in `PublicTransportation` that all subclasses then override? You could also implement `Cloneable`

Comment: I thought this was what `Object.clone()` was for.

Comment: Do you really want copies of the objects, not just copies of the references?  This sounds like a potential [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) until you tell us _why_ you want copies.

Comment: @arcy Object.clone only works if you implement Cloneable